# How do i perform File I/O on a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, io

How do I perform File I/O on a WCF service?

It seems to be working fine in the emulator because it doesn't give me an error, but when I deploy it onto the local IIS 7 it gives me this:

> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

I am basically trying to generate XLS files using the service. Since I'm really new to WCF I don't know if the api I'm using is wrong. I'm just using the file stream object to write the data. I think it has something to do with the location of the file I'm writing to but I can't find any tutorials on how to write data into files.

Comment: Have you checked if IIS has permission to write to the location?

Comment: You're giving us the stack trace - but not the **error message** .....

Comment: There is nothing special or "magic" about doing I/O inside a WCF service method - it's just plain old .NET code. What you need to check is whether or not the **location** you're trying to write your files to is writable for the user account your code is running under.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your IIS App Pool Identity. The set identity must have write permissions on folder you are creating the xls files.

Answer (score 0):

its works for me, AP Poool must have the write permission, The set identity must have write permissions on folder you are creating the xls files.